Bringing homemade sweet bread into Australia
Can I bring home-baked bread containing raisins and apples into Australia? It is shelf stable, does not require refrigeration and is for family consumption

That should be fine (https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in/categories/food)
However, you will never know for sure until you actually get there. Australia is very careful and the final decision lies with the customs officers. There is a small chance that it will get rejected.
You really SHOULD declare it on your arrival form: the officer will likely ask you a few questions about it. Generally this will be a quick and courteous conversation, so there is nothing to worry about. Over-declaring is perfectly fine and strongly encouraged. Under-declaring is NOT a good idea.
One minor nitpick. I would NOT call it "sweetbread" or "sweetbreads," as these terms are commonly used for organ meats which I would definitely not bring.

In the UK it is often called fruit bread. Not sure about Australian English.

@mdewey I'd just call it raisinbread, given that that's just what it is at the core

@jwenting raisin bread is what I'd call it too (I'm from NZ but probably the same in Oz)

Possibly fruit loaf (also from UK).
